# solidity - check bignumber returned from solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

I am using truffle, but that shouldn't make any difference here...

When using contract's transfer mehtod, I want to pass a parameter - 1000000000000000000000000, but since this is too big, it results in an error. That's why I pass `web3.utils.toBN('1000000000000000000000000')`

After that, I should check if one of the address in solidity holds this amount of tokens.

So I have this:

`let balance = await instance.balanceOf(address);`

This returns a bigNumber.

Way 1: To get an actual number so that I can test if it worked, I tried this: `balance.toNumber()` which didn't work.

Way 2: Then, I tried  `assert.equal(balance, web3.utils.toBN('1000000000000000000000000'));`, but now, it shows an error -       `AssertionError: expected <BN: d3c21bcecceda1000000> to equal <BN: d3c21bcecceda1000000>` even though they still seem equal.

My question would be what way do you choose to work with such cases ? Way 1 or Way 2? and if so, how do I fix my issue then ? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to display the balance just do `balance.toString()`. If you need to do some mathematical operations you can do them while variable `balance` is still a BigNumber, then after you can display the outcome again with `.toString()`.

Comment: One question Miroslav. I am writing tests in web3 for my contracts. If I work with the big numbers that returned from solidity, I have to also transform all other numbers to bignumbers too. basically I can't do the following -   balance - 30.  if balance is returned from solidity, then I have to transform 30 into bignumber to make it work. and it gets super awkward to transform all test numbers into bignumbers in my tests. makes sense ?